# If a professor has 7 students and they have to at least do 2 assignments each...

Tags: probability

The professor has $7$ students. Each student has to do at least $2$ projects. There are $3$ projects: $A, B,$ and $C$. Project $A$ has been assigned $4$ times. $B$ has been assigned $5$ times. $C$ has been assigned $6$ times. How many different ways can the projects be assigned?

Comment: By "Project $A$ has been assigned $4$ times" do you mean that the professor needs to assign Project $A$ to $4$ of his $7$ students?

Comment: Can a student be assigned the same project twice? Presumeably "not" but please specify.

Answer (score 4):

There are $7$ students, and the number of project assignments is $4+5+6=15$. Since every student did at least $2$ (presumably different!) projects, one overburdened student did $3$, and the others did $2$ each.

The student who did $3$ can be chosen in $\binom{7}{1}$ ways. Now we must distribute the remaining projects, $2$ of each, between the remaining $6$ students.

There are $3$ remaining A, $4$ remaining B, and $5$ remaining C. The students who do project  A can be chosen in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways. Of these, $1$ must do B, and $2$ must do C. The student who does B can be chosen in $\binom{3}{1}$ ways, and now the rest of the assignments are determined, for a total of $\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{1}$.

There are many other ways of counting.

Answer (score 0):

One other way is to add 6 dummy projects (3 of A, 2 of B and 1 of C) so that each notionally gets 3 of each type, and then withdraw the dummy projects in ${7\choose 3}{4\choose 2}{2\choose 1}$ ways.